# How to recover when Selenium cannot find element

Tags: ruby, if-statement, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to update work contacts automatically by using Selenium and Ruby. I have a CSV of contact names that I match with the names on the web page. The web page only displays 50 contacts at a time, with a Next button to move on. When my ruby script reaches a name (i.e. `"Barbara"`, the 51st contact), the script cannot locate the element because `"Barbara"` is not on the first page, it's on the next page.

When the WebDriver cannot find the page element, it raises the error:

> Failures:
>       1) RackspaceAutomation test_rackspace_automation
>          Failure/Error: @driver.find_element(:link, row[0]).click
>          Selenium::WebDriver::Error:NoSuchElementError:
>          Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector:":"Barbara"}

and exits the program. Instead, when it does not find the given name, I want the `@driver.find_element(:id, "Next").click` line executed and the name to be searched for again.

I've made some changes to handle the error. Code so far:

> CSV.foreach('C:\Users\James\SeleniumTests\WebbContactsFullCVS.cvs') do |row|

```
  begin
    @driver.find_element(:link, row[0]).click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Contact Information").click
    # ERROR: Caught exception [ReferenceError: selectLocator is not defined]
    a=@driver.find_element(:id,'PhoneNumberType')
    options=a.find_elements(:tag_name=>"option")
    options.each do |g|
      if g.text == "Mobile"
        g.click
        break
      end
    end
    @driver.find_element(:id, "MobilePhone").send_keys row[1]
    # ERROR: Caught exception [ReferenceError: selectLocator is not defined]
    options.each do |g|
      if g.text == "Fax"
        g.click
        break
      end
    end
    @driver.find_element(:id, "Fax").send_keys row[2]
    @driver.find_element(:css, "button.primary").click
  rescue NoSuchElementError
    @driver.find_element(:id, "Next").click
    retry
  end
end
```

Getting the error:

> Failures:
>      1) RackspaceAutomation test_rackspace_automation
>         Failure/Error: rescue NoSuchElementError
>         NameError:
>             uninitialized constant NoSuchElementError
>         #   ./RackspaceAutomation.rb:57:in 'rescue in block (3 levels) in '
>         #   ./RackspaceAutomation.rb:35:in 'block (3 levels) in '
>         #   ./RackspaceAutomation.rb:35:in 'block (2 levels) in '

, new to Ruby, so not sure how/where to initialize it.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class NoSuchElementError < Exception
end

names = %w[ a b c ]
on_page = %w[ a b ]

names.each do |name|
  begin
    raise NoSuchElementError if not on_page.include? name
  rescue NoSuchElementError
    puts "rescuing: #{name}"
    on_page = %w[c d]
    retry
  end
end

--output:--
rescuing: c
```

So you can do something like this:

```
names.each do |name|
  begin
    #error throwing code here
  rescue NoSuchElementError
    @driver.find_element(:id, "Next").click
    retry
  end
end
```

Comment: 1) Yes, my first code example models what you are trying to do, and I displayed some output, so you can tell the code did something.  2)  Your error throwing code is the same thing as your _normally run code_.  Put that code where the comment is in the second code example

Comment: When your program exits due to the NoSuchElementError, the error message should state what line in your program raised the error.  That's your _error throwing code_.

Comment: You will need to skip the retry if the click() doesn't return a page.

Comment: So I ran this and got the same error messages as before. Is there some kind of include or "require" I need to handle errors?

Comment: Code posted in edits. Could you explain the "skip the retry" part?

Comment: Post your _original_ error, i.e. the one you got that prompted you to post your question. The error message you posted is from the line: `rescue NoSuchElementError`.  Was that in your original code?

Comment: My original code was what was between the begin and rescue. With that original code, it would error when trying to find the element. The full error are in my edits.

Comment: Try `rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError`

Comment: ...or if you write: `include Selenium::WebDriver::Error`, then you can write `rescue NoSuchElementError`